# Trying to run Signalr client on the server side NodeJS

Tags: node.js, signalr

I have a 3rd party server that runs SignalR. In order to connect to that server and read messages i have created a javascript code that should run from NodeJS on ec2 (Linux) instance. The issue is that when i try running my code that only connects to the server i'm getting this error:
.....node_modules/signalr/jquery.signalR.js:1085
}(window.jQuery, window));
  ^

ReferenceError: window is not defined

What kind of window? I have an ssh-only linux server? My existing JS code is this:

```
const signalR = require("signalr"); //here i can't use @aspnet/signalr or @microsoft/signalr because those aren't compatible with SignalR that's on the 3rd party server. UGH Microsoft!

let connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("https://myurl/signalr/hubName")
    .configureLogging("warn")
        .build();

    connection.start().then(() => {
        console.log("yeeey!");
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
    });
```

What are my options here in order to run this? I have installed NodeJS on ec2 instance using official Amazon tutorial so it should be the latest current version - 13.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution.... [This](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-signalr) library solved my problems

Answer (score -1):

Please write this:

```
import * as signalR from '@aspnet/signalr';
```

Comment: This answer could do with some formatting. Could you also clarify to the questioner how this solves the issue he has?